# How to Render Component sent as a Prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've a component like
    `<A componentAsProps={<Text>Some Text</Text>} />`

How to render componentAsProps in  render method

Answer (score 4):

You can do something this :

```
renderChildCompo = () => <Text>Some text</Text>;

render() {
 return (
   <A componentAsProps={this.renderChildCompo} />
 );
}
// ...
```

And in your ./A/index.js file

```
render() {
 return (
  {this.props.componentAsProps()}
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass a component as children:

**Parent component:**

```
<ChildComponent>
     <Text>Some Text</Text>
</ChildComponent>
```

**Child component:**

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.props.children}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**OR**
you can pass a value as prop and use it like this:

**Parent component:**

```
<ChildComponent text="Some Text" />
```

**Child component:**

```
<Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer all I need to do it 
    `{this.props.componentAsProps}`
in render method of child component